# Angular firebase image saving before record saving to the database using concat

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm having issue in implementing the logic of saving image to firebase, getting back the url to the form img value and save the form value in the database, the issue is that while I get the form url updated correctly inside the firebase saving subscription, I get the same form url empty in the response of the second saving sub!

code:

```js
  upload(): void {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.selectedFiles = undefined;
    let currentFileUpload = new FileUpload(file);

    this.pushedFile$ = this.service.pushFileToStorage(currentFileUpload).pipe(
      map(url => {
        this.service.form.patchValue({ img: url });
        console.log("inside upload:", this.service.form.value)
      })
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {

    this.upload();
    
    let save$ = this.service.save(this.service.form.value).pipe(map(data => console.log("save data: ", data) ));

    concat(this.pushedFile$, save$).subscribe((data => console.log("subscription: ", data)));
  }

  pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload): Observable<any> {
    const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${fileUpload.file.name}`;
    const storageRef = this.firebaseStorage.ref(filePath);
    const uploadTask = this.firebaseStorage.upload(filePath, fileUpload.file);

    return <Observable<any>>uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      last(),
      mergeMap(() => {
        return storageRef.getDownloadURL().pipe(
          map((url) => url)
        )
      })
    );
}
```

inspector output:

licons/v109/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2
abstract-form.component.ts:43 inside upload: {id: null, name: 'Sudan', nameAr: null, quantityPerUnit: null, img: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pos-ad…=media&token=960e9251-6ef8-4e01-8efa-a54745f9906f', …}averageCost: nullbarcode: nullcategory: nulldiscount: nullid: nullimg: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pos-admin-f8a9f.appspot.com/o/products%2Fmaryam.jpg?alt=media&token=960e9251-6ef8-4e01-8efa-a54745f9906f"name: "Sudan"nameAr: nullquantity: nullquantityPerUnit: nullsellPrice: 11supplier: nullvatPercentage: nullvatValue: null[[Prototype]]: Object
abstract-form.component.ts:54 subscription:  undefined
abstract-form.component.ts:52 save data:  {id: 132, name: 'Sudan', nameAr: null, img: null, barcode: null, …}averageCost: nullbarcode: nullcategory: nulldepreciation: nulldiscount: nullid: 132img: nullname: "Sudan"nameAr: nullquantity: nullquantityPerUnit: nullsellPrice: 11supplier: nullvatPercentage: nullvatValue: null[[Prototype]]: Object
abstract-form.component.ts:54 subscription:  undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using concatAll()

```
let pushedFile$ = this.service.pushFileToStorage(currentFileUpload).pipe(map(url => item["img"] = url));

let combined$ = of(pushedFile$, save$);

combined$.pipe(concatAll()).subscribe();
```